# How to expose MariaDB in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mariadb

I have a Docker container with MariaDB running in Microk8s (running on a single Unix machine).

```
# Hello World Deployment YAML
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mariadb
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mariadb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mariadb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mariadb
        image: mariadb:latest
        env:
        - name: MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: sa
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
```

These are the logs:

```
(...)
2021-09-30  6:09:59 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.6.4-MariaDB-1:10.6.4+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

Now,

- connecting to port 3306 on the machine does not work.
- connecting after exposing the pod with a service (any type) on port 8081 also does not work.

How can I get the connection through?

Comment: Do you want to expose the mariaDB outside of the cluster or just inside the cluster, to other Pods?

Comment: @AndD outside..

Comment: @DomJourneyman pls share your service

Comment: @Brucewayne-TheGeekKiller No service def, I use ```kubectl expose```. Plus, I use another pod directly, the service port is not working

Comment: did you get solution??

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? How did you check your connection? Please, show your logs from database's pod.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Yes, it was enough adding a service with spec.selector set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has been written in comments section, but to clarify I am posting here solution as Community Wiki.

In this case problem with connection has been resolved by setting [`spec.selector`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#selector).

> The `.spec.selector` field defines how the Deployment finds which Pods to manage. In this case, you select a label that is defined in the Pod template (`app: nginx`).

> `.spec.selector` is a required field that specifies a [label selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) for the Pods targeted by this Deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the service with proper label

example service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mariadb
spec:
  selector:
    name: mariadb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  type: ClusterIP
```

you can use the service name to connect or else change the service type as **LoadBalancer** to expose it with IP.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mariadb
spec:
  selector:
    name: mariadb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  type: LoadBalancer
```